# Custom PersonalActions menu item not showing on sub sites

Tags: 2010, site

I've got this code adding a menu item to the PersonalActions menu. It works on the main site but not on sub sites, any ideas why?

elements.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Elements Id="9876b641-54a4-433e-8a4d-6a5d4eb34f81" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/">
  <CustomAction
    Id="ID_ResetPassword"
    GroupId="PersonalActions"
    Location="Microsoft.SharePoint.StandardMenu"
    Sequence="1000"
    Title="Reset Password"
    Description="Reset your password">
    <UrlAction Url="schemes/Documents/ResetPassword.aspx"/>
  </CustomAction>
</Elements>
```

edit: as recommended by TimeToThine i've added a feature.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Feature  Id="59dc5cf5-de9f-44ab-8c3e-a5923494ae47"
      Title="BlankFeature1"
      Description="Description for BlankFeature1"
      Version="12.0.0.0"
      Hidden="FALSE"
      Scope="Site"
      DefaultResourceFile="core"
      xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/">
  <ElementManifests>
    <ElementManifest Location="elements.xml"/>    
  </ElementManifests>
</Feature>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right I've figured it out now so posting this incase someone else has the same issue.

In the pkg folder (will need to select show all files in solution explorer to see it) there was a couple of sub folders each with a feature.xml file in them. These were set to Scope=Web, despite the main feature.xml file (in the OP) being set to Scope=Site. I changed these to Scope=Site and it works great now :D.

Not sure if this was the root cause of the problem but hey it works so I'm happy xD.

Answer (score 0):

For all the examples I am looking into since yesterday for my custom action I am developing for `GroupId="ActionsMenu" I didn't seen any of element tag has any id like yours

```
<Elements Id="9876b641-54a4-433e-8a4d-6a5d4eb34f81"
```

So not sure if that's the issue, also can you add code for feature your using as need to check what's its scope. e.g. if you want it to activate feature for all sites within a site collection then code should be something like this,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Feature  Id="GUID-ID"
          Title="abc"
          Description="Description for ab"
          Version="12.0.0.0"
          Hidden="FALSE"
          Scope="Site" // for site collection it has to be site, and web for a single site
```

Hope it helps ;)

**EDIT**

In your  `<UrlAction Url="schemes/Documents/ResetPassword.aspx"/>`try to put this page in layout folder in 12 hive (in SharePoint 2007) with right permissions, e.g.

```
C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\web server extensions\12\TEMPLATE\LAYOUTS
```

or WSP Builder can do it for you, just make another folder named as "LAYOUTS" in your "TEMPLATE" folder in Visual studio folder structure and add your existing resetpassword.aspx page to it, might help.

in end your URLAction will be like:

```
<UrlAction Url="/_layouts/ResetPassword.aspx"/>
```

Comment: Thanks for reply, how would I add a feature? I'm using VS2008 and all tutorials I can find are using VS2010.

Comment: Use WSB builder extension for visual studio http://wspbuilder.codeplex.com/ , it will make your life way easier trust me ;)

Comment: OK i've added a feature but it's made no difference, also if I take out the ID from the elements tag the menu item isn't displayed.